# Angular orderBy not ordering array of strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to sort data, but the values are not getting sorted, and I am not sure why.

This is inside the template of my `Modal`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter items" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchText | orderBy">
        <a href="#" ng-click="selected.item = item">{{item}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The Array I am filtering looks something like this:

```
{
    "actions": [
        "Views",
        "Clicks",
        "Uploads",
        "Downloads"
    ]
}
```

When It builds the list, the order of the items don't change, so I am thinking I am doing something wrong with the `orderBy`. I have also tried `orderBy:'toString()'` as others have suggested, but that doesn't work either.

Here is what I am doing with the JavaScript (I am not sure if this is important), I am using an [Angular Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal):

```
app.directive('events', function($modal, $http){
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/widgets/event.html',
        scope: {
            source: '@'
        },
        link: function($scope){
            $scope.items = [];

            $http({
                url: $scope.source
            }).success(function(data){
                $scope.items = data;
            });

            $scope.open = function(modalData){
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    controller: 'eventOptions',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/modals/event.html',
                    resolve: {
                        items: function(){
                            return $scope.items;
                        },
                        modalData: function(){
                            return modalData;
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
});

app.controller('eventOptions', function($scope, $modalInstance, items, modalData){

    $scope.items = items[modalData];

    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function(){
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you create an MCVE?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally figured it out (by doing some housekeeping), I just needed to change my resolve to this:

```
resolve: {
    items: function(){
        return $scope.items[modalData];
    }
}
```

I then changed this within the controller:

```
$scope.items = items[modalData];
```

Too this:

```
$scope.items = items;
```